# Ember Data 2.0 findAll dont work

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a problem, I wrote a little code to access the data band through a servlet, I am trying to use the ember date to make REST calls, however I am having problems using the store.findAll only to find works normal with the findAll returns the following error:

> Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() to set the `content`
>   property (of ) to ``.

follows some information that can be useful:

**Model name:** veiculo
**Servlet path(GET):** api/veiculos

below is the code only the javascript because the html and just to show the same result.

Adapter:

```
//Setup RESTApi
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    host        : 'http://localhost:8080/app-test',
    namespace   : 'api',
});
```

Model:

```
// Veiculos model
App.Veiculo = DS.Model.extend({
    placa               : DS.attr( 'string' ),
    marca               : DS.attr( 'string' ),
    modelo              : DS.attr( 'string' ),
    ano                 : DS.attr( 'number' ),
    cor                 : DS.attr( 'string' ),
    cpfproprietario_fk  : DS.attr( 'string' ),
});

App.VeiculoSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: 'placa'
});
```

the strange thing is that no servlet and called with the findAll, but to find work normal this hard to find updated material Ember Data, already tried using RESTAdapter, and tried to use the App.Store also and also did not work.

Sorry english is google trans.

Comment: The same code in ember 1.13.10 and ember data 1.13.11 works fine, can be a bug or anything changed between versions

Comment: See http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/ for deprecations between 1.13.11 and 2.0

Comment: This bug only occurs in version 2.0.1, the version 2.0.2 is already standard

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ember Data >=2.0, you'll want to drop this in `app/serializers/veiculos.js` - or `application.js` to have it apply to all models:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: 'placa'
});
```

See here: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#property_primaryKey